# error CS1502 after upgrade to 2sxc 09.08.00

Tags: 2sxc

after upgrading 2sxc to 09.08.00 we get an error:
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.SexyContentWebPage.AsDynamic(ToSic.Eav.Interfaces.IEntity)' has some invalid arguments at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult

So the part it talks about is:
var Content = AsDynamic(dict.Value);

What should I do about this?????

Comment: Please add more detail. Include enough code to communicate the full context. What have you attempted so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, it looks like I had to change AsDynamic(dict.Value); to AsDynamic(dict); for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for context - because of new features related to using data from any kind of source (json, sql, web-api, csv, etc.) we had to change how we work with lists of items.

Previously, all items were handled in dictionaries, so the list was a `Dictionary<entityId, entity>`, which meant that you had to use `.Value`. This ID=Key would have caused a lot of problems in the future, because lists containing persons and lists containing pages could both have the same ID, basically breaking any dictionary-setup.

So in 9.8 we were forced to introduce a breaking change 
See also: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases/tag/v09.08.00

We didn't do this lightly, but it's an essential step towards opening up the EAV & 2sxc for upcoming features. Sorry about this!